# Pass variable to .animate property

Tags: animation, positioning, var

Bit of a n00b here.
I was trying to modify a hover function I'd found which positions and animates an image within a list item. Instead of giving .animate({top: an exact pixel value in the first instance, I wanted to pass it the variable imgHeight, which gets the height of the containing li, but I'm clearly doing something wrong. Any pointers?

```
var imgHeight = $('li').height();
$(function() {
$('ul.hover_block li').hover(function(){
$(this).find('img').animate({top:'imgHeight' + 'px'},{queue:false,duration:200});
}, function(){
$(this).find('img').animate({top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:200});
});
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: you had

```
{top: 'imgHeight' + 'px'}
```

Should be

```
{top: imgHeight + 'px'}
```

Full code:

```
var imgHeight = $('li').height();
$(function() {
        $('ul.hover_block li').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('img').animate({top:imgHeight + 'px'},{queue:false,duration:200});
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('img').animate({top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:200});
      });
});​
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! It was probably the only variation I hadn't tried. How dumb do I feel...

Comment: Not a problem man. JQuery's got a bit of a learning curve, but when you get it down you won't know how you ever lived without it